# Backbone constructor calls itself

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I've encountered a problem I don't understand. I'm playing with Backbone and one of my initializer is called twice, one on purpose (when I instantiate my object) and it seems like it's called a second time from the constructor itself.

Here is my code :

```
class Views extends Backbone.Collection

    model: View

    initialize: ->
        _.bindAll @

class View extends Backbone.View

    initialize: ->
        _.bindAll @
        console.error 'Inner'

views = new Views
console.log 'Outer' 
views.add new View
```

When I run this code, `Outer` is displayed once while `Inner` is displayed 2 times. Here is the stack trace :

[image]

Any idea about this ?

Comment: Could be some issue with your router, calling your view twice. Happens often, when you develop Backbone applications. Your code at this points seems ok. Try debugging through Chrome, by setting breakpoints in your application (especcially your router) -> https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize a collection, the first argument is the list of models to pre-populate it with.

```
class Models extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Model 

    initialize: (@rawModels) ->
        # CoffeeScript has the fat arrow that renders this unnecessary.
        # But it's something you should use as sparingly as possible.
        # Whatever. Not the time to get into that argument.
        _.bindAll @ 

        # At this point in time, all the models have been added to the
        # collection. Here, you add them again. IF the models have a
        # primary key attribute, this will detect that they already
        # exist, and not actually add them twice, but this is still
        # unnecessary.
        _.each @rawModels, @addItem

    # assuming this was a typo
    addItem: ( place ) -> @add new Model model

models = new Models json
```

Not directly related to your question, but hopefully helpful.

More directly related: don't create a collection of views. `Collection`s are for storing `Model`s. `Backbone.View` is not a type of `Backbone.Model`; they're separate. It doesn't really make sense -- you can just create an array of views -- and a lot of operations won't work right on that view collection.

Which is what's happening here.

When you call `Backbone.Collection::add`, it tries to see if what you're adding is a `Backbone.Model`. Since it's *not*, it assumes you're trying to add a JSON blob that it wants to turn into a `Model`. So it tries to do that...using its `this.model` class as a guide. But since that's `View`, it creates another one and adds that instead (not checking after the fact that it actually produced a `Backbone.Model`).

You can follow the call stack from add to set to [_prepareModel](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-109), where the second `View` is instantiated.